# Android widget-ImageView issue/error

Tags: android, android-widget

For the life of me I can't run this on my android emulator;I'm new to this but I thought getting an image output should be easy!

I get these two errors in Eclipse(Android plug-in)IDE

```
1.findViewbyId cannot be resolved
2.the method setImageView(String) is undefined for the type catwalk
```

Please see the code below

```
package com.marueli.catwalk;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Catwalk extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ImageView(findViewById);

        setImageView("R.drawable.Cat.PNG");

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

          }
}
```

It is my first code after going through several tutorials.Thank you.

Regards,
Eli.

Answer (score 1):

findViewById is a method and R.drawable.cat is a variable.

try.

```
package com.marueli.catwalk;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Catwalk extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.image_view_id);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat);

    }
}
```

image_view_id is the android:id of the image view in your main.xml file and i am assuming that in your drawable directory you have a file name cat.png.

Comment: Thanks Robby for a very fast response.